# SQL Query returns too much data

Tags: sql

Im trying to define an **authorities-by-username-query:** for Spring Security

```
SELECT u.username, r.authrole FROM users u, roles r, user_role ur 
                   WHERE u.id = ur.userid AND u.username = 'dit'
```

Its embarrassing, but this query returns wrong result and i can't fix it.

**Result:**

```
 username     authrole  
-----------------------
   dit       ROLE_ADMIN   
   dit       ROLE_USER
```

here are my tables:

**users:**

```
   id    username   password
---------------------------------
    1      admin     *****
    2       dit      *****
```

**user_role:**

```
  userid   roleid  
---------------------
    1        1   
    2        2
```

**roles:**

```
  id     authrole  
---------------------
  1     ROLE_ADMIN   
  2     ROLE_USER
```

UPDATE: i took this bad query from this [example on github](https://github.com/krimple/spring-roo-in-action-examples/blob/master/chapter-08-security/votesecure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml)

Comment: Is 'Result' your expected result?

Comment: `FROM users u JOIN user_role ur ON u.id = ur.userid JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.roleid WHERE u.username = 'dit'` - Use real joins instead of implied cross joins, this is especially crucial if you don't know how to check you're doing your joins correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this (NOTE: the INNER keyword is optional):

```
SELECT u.username
       ,r.authrole
  FROM users u 
  INNER JOIN user_role ur 
    ON u.id = ur.userid 
  INNER JOIN roles r 
    ON r.id = ur.roleid 
  WHERE u.username = 'dit'
```

The problem was that you were joing the roles table without giving any conditions on how to joing the table.  The result will be a cartesian product, where every possible combinations between the tables being joined is displayed.

Rather then joining in the WHERE clause it is better (more clear) to use the JOIN syntax. Also, and more importantly, using JOIN syntax creates a separation of concerns. Putting the fields you are using to join the tables in the where clause can lead to difficulties in understand queries.

There are essentially four different kinds of joins:

- INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table
- RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table
- FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

Comment: Your information on joins is correct, but please break them down correctly. You have three main types of outer join: left, right and full, these return null for entries that don't exist on the relevant side of the join, and three types of inner join, natural(matches based on columns with the same name, don't trust it), inner (has an on clause) and cross(doesn't have an on clause, causes a Cartesian product).